# Magento PWA Studio - That page could not be found. Please try again - for every product

Tags: magento2.3.2, pwa, pwa-studio, venia

I started playing with PWA Studio and installed Venia theme. 
I managed to setup it, but for every product route I get "That page could not be found. Please try again.". 
Data is fetched from Magento correctly.

Example of route `https://magento-venia-concept-tfwxw.local.pwadev:8038/book-1.html`

What could be the issue? 
Thanks.

Comment: What is the backend that you are pointing to in your `.env` file? Are you using the Magento cloud instance that installs by default?

Comment: @circlesix it's my local magento instance with `laravel valet+`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. In https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/blob/fa0a4c9b45757c272f6b745c546e8b61b1da40db/packages/venia-ui/lib/components/SearchBar/suggestedProduct.js#9 (same thing for `categoryTile.js` and `categoryLeaf.js`) `.html` is hardcoded in.

Just set the `suffix` to empty string and it will work.

Comment: Hello is any command need to run again after changes in pwa component , i mean js file ?